# URL redirect + VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I am creating an Add-in for Outlook 2010. Once the button is clicked, the email and subject will be saved to database (this is fine) and will also redirect to a URL. Could you please tell me how to do the URL redirection for VSTO? Not sure if that is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Process.Start()` to open the URL in the user's default web browser as follows:

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"http://www.google.com");`

or more simply (as you found out):

`Process.Start(@"http://www.google.com");`

To be clear, you're not *redirecting*, just simply browsing to the URL in a new window.

Comment: this one works for me `Process.Start("http://www.google.com");`
still, your answer is correct! thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I updated my answer to include the shorter version of the command that you settled with.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a outlook form region you use, you could use the Navigate2 of the SHDocVw.WebBrowser

I am not sure if you wanted to open a new url in the default web browser.